# Windows 8 app load web app from url

Tags: windows-8

I've developed an Android app who loads a web app from an url in fullscreen and caches it with application cache. That works fine, so I would do the same for Windows 8. Is this possible? How it's done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load any WebSite/WebApp in your windows-8 app, you can add `WebView` control in your ApplicationPage.

You can find more details/Information regarding `WebView` control [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227702)

and find Code samples for Adding `WebView` in your app [**here**](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7)

For detailed answer, you have to elaborate your question more.